# Alternative to slip string in this scenario?

Tags: php

I have the following information to dynamicaly display:

Product XYZ

Very nice

Very good

Very cool

Those Very nice, very good, very cool are advantages of a given product, textual, description advantages, normally display in a form of bullets.

I guess that it makes no sense to store those on a separate table called advantages, because it will never be used to anything else despite display, and I fill it as too overkill.

So I was thinking about creating a varchar255 field on this product table, and allow values to be inserted like:

Very nice;Very good;Very cool

On a free-form text input field.

Then split those on a php array.

My question is: Is it out there, a better approach ?

Comment: Please define Very Nice, Very Good, and Very Cool?  IS it like Bad, OKay, Great?   is this suppose to be a voting system or sorts?

Comment: what you are saying is correct then you could just explode and spend database tables it is a good approach

Comment: Well and are they free-form text snipptes or a limited set of qualifiers?

Comment: Sounds like a case for [localization](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php). Personally, I would feel it a waste of time to query a database very frequently for a short string of multiple values. But it's not unheard. I'd just put it in some kind of resource file, like a localization file (even if you only have one).

Comment: you should consider data type SET

Comment: If you're trying to store an array in a field, then your database design is wrong. Implement a many-to-many relationship between products and descriptions.

Comment: @JanTuroň suggestion makes sense, I believe. On those cases, a set data type may fit. The user enters the data as comma separated values or whatever, then, those will be stored on a set data type for later retrieval.

Comment: @WaleedKhan - not sure if the approach is that strict. I mean, having a many to many table, when EVER will those elements be sorted out, or worked out someway, seems to overkill.

Comment: @All: I've updated my question for clarification proposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These solutions cross my mind:

- If you want lookup product by its advantage and you have less than 64 advantages, an index in your DB should be on the attribute and you should use the [SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html) data type, plus it saves the space used.
- If you don't need the index and the advantages may be any vague description, then I find your approach OK.
- If those combinations are finite, you can create extra table with all of these combinations and insert just the combination id to your product table. It is hard to insert (check if the combination is already in the table, eventually insert new combination and write its id to product table), but easy to read.
- In a company I was working for, we also used the approach advantage1, advantage2 ... advantageN column in the table. It is not 2NF, but if you want the user directly input these values (as you noted in the comments), you can just create advantage1, advantage2 ... advantageN input fields in the form and [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Answer (score 1):

If your texts `very nice, very good, very cool` are `Constant` and they are not changing from product to product, I would use something like this:

```
// text from database, '-' means nothing
$a = 'NGC-------';

if ($a[0] == 'N')
    echo 'Very Nice';

if ($a[1] == 'G')
    echo 'Very Good';

// and so on ...
```

By the way, it will save lots of spaces on your database, and nothing more. :)

Comment: You can also use "11011..." format or just use UNSIGNED INT data type and perform bit operations. However, it is basically the same as SET data type, just the conversion is made by DBMS for you.

Comment: @JanTuroň yes, with letters it's just a little bit easier to understand and doesn't need bit operations. :)